Manga with a female main character who is bethrothed to a prince who can't use magic
It's a manga (not a manhua/manhwa) where the main character (MC) is female. I'm not sure if it's a reincarnation manga, but I think it is, since I know the MC quickly becomes powerful in using magic since she's young. She also becomes engaged to a prince (not the crown prince) who cannot use magic, also while they are young. The crown prince was trained by the MC in using magic. The MC also invented a magic tool useful for visualizing mana, I think; it was eyeglasses that the crown prince used to train his magic.
I just can't recall the name of this manga.

Just to confirm - the prince is definitely a guy? Meaning this isn't The Magical Revolution of the Reincarnated Princess and the Genius Young Lady?

Yep, definitely a guy with short dark hair, also a bit older than MC, they're definitely not of the same age

Are there any other details you can recall? The prince is a little older than the MC, but how old is that? Children? Teenagers? Young adult? Does the crown prince also have dark/black hair? Does the training take place in an academy setting, or as private tutoring, or something else?

Children, MC and the crown prince are definitely children (6-7) while the prince looked pre-teen. Crown prince is light-haired and the training is private tutoring.

Wild guess: Head Start at Birth. I'm out of free chapters so I can't confirm if she becomes the older prince's tutor. I was skimming but I didn't see a mention of him not being able to use magic. But she's at least a super-strong young reincarnated magician

Two other series with child genius protagonists: "Shindou Sefiria no Gekokujou Program", "Tensei Youjo wa Akiramenai". I don't recall anything about princes, but I didn't read every chapter. I haven't been able to find anything that's a better match.

It seems I mistaken the king's nephew for one of the other princes but yeah, it's head start at birth. Thank you.



HEAD START AT BIRTH
Genre(s)
Adaptation, Adventure, Drama, Fantasy, Isekai, Isekai Genre, Romance
SUMMARY
This is a tale of Lilia with her new game cheat as she becomes known
as the marquess’ daughter who is a genius at both magic and
territorial management.
Having been born with memories of her past life intact and after
learning that the world that she has been reborn in has magic, Lilia’s
past life’s gamer spirit can’t help but go on full blast!
She started leveling up even from when she was only a 0 year old baby
who could only babble! Thanks to that, by the time she was 5 years
old, not only could she already use high-grade magic, she also had
high ranking spirits serving her. She even exhibited great capability
in managing the marquess territory!
No matter if this world were an RPG or a farming game, this cheat is
surely unbeatable! And that was what Lilia was thinking until she had
suddenly caught the attention of the royal family and was even invited
to the royal capital to celebrate her birthday.
Who would have thought she would actually raise a political marriage
flag with the princes, just like in an otome game!? Just please let me
at least not be a villainess noble lady!!!


Hi, it's great that you found it, but can you provide a description and maybe a link?

Please don't forget to mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
